# You're Surely Joking Mr. Review Audits!

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-audit

Whenever I start doing the review process, and that I see the two following characteristics, I automatically know that it is a review audit:

- No username.
- The image that a suppressed account gets.

As an example:

[image: example]

(Plus this is clearly written in pure Bill's style)

It will be more convenient if in place of the characteristics listed above, they were random names and random images.

Comment: This isn't really a bug though, is it? These audits are for people who aren't paying the least amount of attention.

Comment: @mixedmath I mean even if someone does the click-click-click strategy and he knew a little about the reviews audit system, then he'll be able to recognize posts like those just because they don't contain the username and no image.

Comment: Yes, cunning people who aim to misbehave will misbehave cunningly. But they are *few* in number, and therefore are not considered a problem worth designing software for.

Comment: Even if random names and images were used, you can still follow the $\color {blue}{\text{link}}$ to see the "real" answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not a bug. The audit system is not meant to throw curveballs at reviewers. A reviewer who is *paying some attention* to what's shown on the screen will be able to recognize audits in certain queues.

The audits are aimed at the "robo-reviewers" who go click-click-click without looking at the posts *at all*.

Comment: I think it's equally arguable that the review system *is* intended to throw curve balls at reviewers...

Comment: @CarlMummert The main curve I observe is the tall arc of a slow underhand lob, though :)